# Partial correlation for dichotomous variable in Python

Tags: python, categorical-data, partial-correlation

I would like to compute the partial correlation between a target categorical variable y (= A or B) and a number of numerical (discrete or continuous) predictors.

In the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229220/partial-correlation-in-python

there is a suggestion to use Pingouin:

https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.partial_corr.html

however, I believe that that would work only if the target variable and the predictors are all numerical continuous variables. Is that correct?

I believe that because I have read that for the correlation between a categorical variable with two levels and a continuous variable, one would need to use point biserial correlation. However, in Pingouin, the point biserial correlation option is not available.

Also, more in general, I'm looking for partial correlation of y vs one of the predictors with all the other predictors as covariates. And point biserial correlation would only cover correlation (not partial correlation) and for categorical with two levels vs continuous, while among my predictors I have both continuous and discrete variables.

Comment: A binary variable *is* numeric.

Comment: @MichaelM, I have corrected the text. My question is if I can use pearson, spearman, kendall, or any other from pingouin partial correlation, if y is not a continuous variable. I believe that different approaches have to be used in different cases: continuous vs continuous, continuous vs discrete and discrete vs discrete.

Comment: As long as it is about *descriptive* figures, it is no problem.

Comment: @MichaelM, what do you mean precisely with _descriptive_ figures? I'm not looking for a relative importance of the predictors. I would like to have also an accurate value of the "magnitude" of the correlation.

Comment: Descriptive in contrast to inferential statistics like p values or confidence intervals.

Comment: @MichaelM, I understand what you mean. Partial correlation is a descriptive figure. However, I'm still in doubt on whether I can use the partial correlation from pingouin. I have modified the text again to be more specific. My target variable is by all means a categorical variable with two levels and I believe that its correlation vs a continuous variable should be calculated using point biserial correlation. However, my situation is more complex because I'm looking for partial correlation instead and I have predictors that can be both continuous and discrete.